# company or technology

Tags: job-offer

I am a java guy. I got offers from 2 companies namely A and B.

A is a normal service based company and I will have java there.

B is a branded product based company with extremely good employee_friendly policies.   But they use only fortran which i dont want to learn.

The B offered me 10+% more salary than the A. Even then my sub conscious asks me to take the job from A.

PS: In fact, succeeding the interview process of B itself is a great milestone in my life. On the other hand, Interview with A was a piece of cake to me.
If B had got java, i would have taken the job no matter what my salary is going to be. Because B is such a cool company. 
However, only B use fortran and no other good company in my location, as far as my i know, use fortran. So, it maybe a dead end to my career.

Note: We all are after money. If somebody could give you more money, wouldn't you switch?

Comment: Hey jane, and welcome to [workplace.se]. As explained in our [help/on-topic], *"Questions looking for opinions on what to do but with no specific problem are suited for discussion boards (not a question/answer site) and generally will be closed on The Workplace"*. If you have a specific problem you want help with, please [edit] your question. If you need further help, feel free to ask in [chat]. Thanks in advance!

Comment: chat requires some reputation which i dont have. Can you tranfer me some of yours?.. And lot of programmers have faced this situation at least once. So it needs a good answer

Comment: Your question doesn't really seem to be about tiny company vs. reputed company, but rather widely-used tech vs. little-used tech. Advice on which job to take is off-topic here, but my advice is: 10% more salary is not worth taking your career into a dead-end. Unless you are willing to specialize in Fortran and risk focusing on something few people use in your area, don't go that way just for a little more money *now*.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You are right on the mark.  Fortran is a dead end.  It is not a skill that you are going to be able to use in many places at all.

You can't get too focused on 'cool company' because a 'cool company' can go bankrupt overnight, and then you are stuck.

Comment: Every language comes with distinct paradigms and tools. I don't see how learning FORTRAN could be bad for his career.

Comment: Zip over to DICE.com and compare how many jobs asking for FORTRAN there are compared to how many there are for Java.  Learning FORTRAN?  Nothing wrong with that.  Trying to put food on the table, in the long term?  Fat chance.

Comment: what is the point of downvoting this answer?, If u dont like the question, downvote the question

Comment: @Spidey learning FORTRAN isn't bad in and of itself. It's the opportunity cost. Spend a couple of years working as a FORTRAN developer, and that's a couple of years where you didn't learn more marketable skills, and a couple of years during which the marketable skills you already had atrophied. Now if it was a job where FORTRAN was a small part of it, thus an opportunity to learn something new whilst still using your marketable skills, that would be a different matter...

Comment: @Carson63000 did hit the nail on the head. I am taking your advice.

Comment: @Carson63000 I feel like the OP doesn't want to take the FORTRAN job and is asking for arguments against it. Anyway, maybe I'm just biased AGAINST Java and are suggesting anything around it.

Comment: @Spidey - you may be right on that, and that sort of thing is I think a good reason for career advice to be off-topic.

Comment: @Spidey 
I am not looking for arguements against fortran. In fact the language used in the company is not fortran, it's a out-of-date language like fortran. I did not want to disclose the real langauge and get caught by the potential empolyer hence the masking. Btw the company discussed here was my dream company during my college days. Now i've got a chance and not be able to make it :(